# best way to bundle update on server while booting

Tags: ruby, git, amazon-ec2, bundle, unicorn

I have an AMI which has configured with production code setup.I am using Nginx + unicorn as server setup. 
The problem I am facing is, whenever traffic goes up I need to boot the instance log in to instance and do a git pull,bundle update and also precompile the assets.Which is time consuming.So I want to avoid all this process.

Now I want to go with a script/process where I can automate whole deployment process, like git pull, bundle update and precompile as soon as I boot a new instance from this AMI.

Is there any best way process to get this done ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `capistrano` have many task for this, you can write recipe for bundle update/install and restart `unicorn`(restart kill worker one by one and launch them).

Answer (score 0):

You can place your code in /etc/rc.local (commands in this file will be executed when server will be loaded).

But the best way is using ([capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)). You need to add `require "capistrano/bundler"` to your deploy.rb file, and bundle update will be runned automatically. For more information you can read this article: https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2013/11/26/capistrano-3-upgrade-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to deploy your app to a separate EBS volume (you can still mount this inside /var/www/application or wherever it currently is)

After deploying you create an EBS snapshot of this volume. When you create a new instance, you tell ec2 to create a new volume for your instance from the snapshot, so the instance will start with the latest gems/code already installed (I find bundle install can take several minutes). All your startup script needs to do is to mount the volume (or if you have added it to the fstab when you make the ami then you don't even need to do that). I much prefer scaling operations like this to have no dependencies (eg what would you do if github or rubygems have an outage just when you need to deploy)

You can even take this a step further by using amazon's autoscaling service. In a nutshell you create a launch configuration where you specify the ami, instance type, volume snapshots etc. Then you control the group size either manually (through the web console or the api) according to a fixed schedule or based on cloudwatch metrics. Amazon will create or destroy instances as needed, using the information in your launch configuration.